# Passing 2D array of strings to a function

Tags: c++, c++17

I can initialize a 2D array of strings using the following:

`const char * const aListOfStrings[] {"test","test1"};`

However, if I want to do the same thing when calling a function, such as:

```
void function( char const * const aListOfStrings[] ) {}

void CallWithArrayOfStrings()
{
    function( {"test", "test1"} );
}
```

The compiler politely refuses with the following error:

```
error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'char**'
```

I am able to pass a single string to a function as in:

```
void function( char const *someString ) {}

void CallWithString()
{
    function( "test" );
}
```

I seem to understand how to initialize arrays when they are variables, but apparently I don't seem to understand how it works in the context of calling functions. I have always assumed that initializing a variable is the same as initializing a function parameter?  Have I been living a lie my whole life? ;)

Thank you

UPATE:  Removed C tag.  C arrays require an '=' sign before the brace initializer, and the error is different. It appears the problem is very similar however...
Also fixed the closing quote.

Comment: `const char * const aListOfStrings[] {"test","test1};`  you missed double quotes at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const char * const aListOfStrings[] {"test","test1"};` is a shorthand for

`const char * const aListOfStrings[2] {"test","test1"};`

Size is deduced.

But arguments of signature are fixed (unless template is used), moreover you cannot pass C-array by value, so:

`void function(char const * const aListOfStrings[])` is equivalent to

`void function(char const * const* aListOfStrings)`.

To have your syntax, you might use the (strange) syntax

```
void function(char const * const (&aListOfStrings)[2]);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ec24443b549212a)

or the template version

```
template <std::size_t N>
void function(char const * const (&aListOfStrings)[N]);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2aca844f79ddd1e)

Comment: Thanks for taking time Jarod in answering this, but I need to keep the size deduction.  Casting works (see my comment above).

Comment: Template version allows deduction (see link demo). With your casting, you don't have size information...

Comment: That makes sense.  I did not think it through...the aListOfStrings[] as a parameter can't know how big it is at compile time, the only way is using a template.  Thanks @Jarod42

Answer (score 1):

That's because your compiler is not guessing the type of your inline argument, passed to `function`, so you must explicitly declare it before, eg:

```
const char* data[] = { "test", "test1" };
function(data);
```

But C++ has `std::array`, `std::initalizer_list`, `std::vector`, there's no reason to use an array of pointers to `char` unless you have a specific requirement.

Comment: I do have a specific requirement.   Using a container isn't an option for this specific instance.  Is it possible to cast it in some way?  And just answered my own question:
function2( ( char const * const []){"test","test2"} );  does the trick nicely.